# Is the SystemModStamp field unique between updates?

Tags: api

Is it ever possible to have two updates by two different users occur at exactly the same time?  I have to save some data in an external system.  I am using Get Updated Objects to extract the latest changes.  There is a chance that we may get the same changes multiple times from Salesforce but I only want to have one update in the internal system.  Short of comparing every single field in a record to what Salesforce sends to see if anything has changed, I was wondering if I can rely on the SystemModStamp to insure the "version authenticity" of a Salesforce record.  In other words, is there a chance to two updates can occur against a Salesforce record that use the same SystemModStamp but actually change different data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The granularity of the systemModStamp field is 1 second, so it seems entirely possible that 2 or more edits could take place within that 1 second. Rather than comparing fields, you could just calculate a hash of the salesforce data and store that to be able to more quickly see if there's a difference between the updated row from salesforce and your externally stored row.